# Unable to store multiple commands in a variable and execute in Bash script

Tags: bash, variables, ssh

I've a Bash script written as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

PINGGOOGLE=echo "<H1>Ping Status</H1>";echo "<table border=\"1\">"; ping -c 3 -w 3 -q 192.168.16.129 | sed '/ping statistics/,$!d';echo "</table>"

echo '<html>' >> pinghost.txt
echo '<body>' >> pinghost.txt
ssh root@192.168.16.130 "${PINGGOOGLE}" >> pinghost.txt    
echo '</body>' >> pinghost.txt
echo '</html>' >> pinghost.txt
```

But script shows error.

If I execute in CLI output is working fine. The problem arises when I store in a variable and use it on remote machine through SSH.

```
echo "<H1>Ping Status</H1>";echo "<table border=\"1\">"; ping -c 3 -w 3 -q 192.168.16.129 | sed '/ping statistics/,$!d';echo "</table>"
```

Comment: I should get output as follows when i use in script.

<H1>Codenvy Ping Status from MS1 server</H1>

<table border="1">

--- 192.168.16.129 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.429/0.527/0.671/0.105 ms

</table>

Comment: `PINGGOOGLE=echo "<H1>Ping Status</H1>"` will (try to) execute a command called `<H1>Ping Status</H1>`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want store the output in text file as i said in my comment

Comment: @hruday You'll have to be more specific than that. Are you trying to assign that whole line to `$PINGGOOGLE`? If so you'll need to qoute it. But *why* do you want to do that? It's only used in one place, and storing commands in strings is [generally a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: anyways that is my requirement now to show output in a table of html

How should i quote it so that i can use it inside script?

Comment: @hruday Time to find a shell/Bash script tutorial or book.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there will be better ways, but this seems OK to me:

```
#!/bin/bash

PINGGOOGLE() { echo "<H1>Ping Status</H1>";echo "<table border=\"1\">"; ping -c 3 -w 3 -q 192.168.16.129 | sed '/ping statistics/,$!d';echo "</table>"; }

echo '<html>' >> pinghost.txt
echo '<body>' >> pinghost.txt
{ declare -f PINGGOOGLE; echo PINGGOOGLE; } | ssh root@192.168.16.130 >> pinghost.txt    
echo '</body>' >> pinghost.txt
echo '</html>' >> pinghost.txt
```

In short, do not put the commands in variables. There are issues with quoting and escaping. Store it in a bash function.

Then pass that function's definition to remote and call that function.

caveats:

1. Local aliases, if any, will be expanded by this method.
2. If the function uses any local system variable, it will not be available on remote system.
3. If the function uses any binary/script that is present only on local system and not on remote, it will not work. (obviously!)